# how do I change a input children value component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I’m wondering how can I change a children input value from main?
Basically I have a component that I’m sending a children, and in this component I want to be able to change the input value.

Here is my main:

```js
 <FooterOptions>
  <input type="text"
  onChange={event=>setState(event.target.value)}
  value={state}
  hidden/>
</FooterOptions>
```

And here is my component:

```js
export function FooterOptions(props:{children: ReactNode}){
  return(
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: are u using  javascript or typescript ?

Comment: I’m using Typescript

Comment: You are already doing value binding to state. ---`value={state}`. So if your `state` state changes then automatically value of input will reflect the same.

Comment: I wanna do that from the component. But I don’t wanna my user doing that, I wanna my code changing that field (that is why is hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `children` prop is something that you can only render onto the page, so there's nothing you can do with it to change the value of the input.

Instead how I would think about this is that you want to provide a mechanism for FooterOptions to change the value of another component. Here it happens to also be rendered as its `children`, but it would work the same even if it was rendered someplace else.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const updateInput = (val) => setState(val)
  return (
    <FooterOptions handleUpdate={updateInput}>
      <input type="text"
        onChange={event=>setState(event.target.value)}
        value={state}
        hidden/>
    </FooterOptions>
  )
}
```

```
export function FooterOptions(props:{children: ReactNode, handleUpdate}){
  // Example handler
  const handleClick = () => handleUpdate('updated inside FooterOptions')
  return(
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you'd like to add more details of how you are hoping to update, then I can add a better example

Comment: Could you please provide more details about `'updated inside FooterOptions'`? Would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Sure, `handleUpdate` is function that will receive a value and update the input with that value. I added that string just as an example, but you would call it with whatever you want. If you add more info about what you're trying to do inside `FooterOptions`, I can provide a better example 

Comment: Sure. I just need to add any string in that input from the children, but I don’t want the user inserting that, I'm wondering the code insert any string there. I'll use it for automation purposes. A not that good example: `props.children.setState("t")` (it doesn’t work)

Comment: The only `children` I can see is the `input` which is rendered as `children` within `FooterOptions`. Like I mentioned above, you wouldn't actually call anything off of children. Instead you would leverage `handleUpdate` with whatever value you want to set. That function will then pass that state back to the `input` (which happens to also be `children`, but it doesn't need to be)